# Call a view from form in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I want to call a view from my html template using forms but when i click on update button nothing happens. I cant seem to find out the error.
Codes are as follows

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<form action = {% url 'update' %} method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">User information</h6>
            <div class="pl-lg-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Company ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="id" disabled="disabled" id="input-username" class="form-control form-control-alternative"
                           value="{{ data.id }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="input-email" class="form-control form-control-alternative" 
                           value="{{ data.email }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-first-name">Company Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="input-first-name" class="form-control form-control-alternative" value="{{ data.name }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="my-4" />
            <!-- Address -->
            <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Contact information</h6>
            <div class="pl-lg-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-address">Address</label>
                    <input id="input-address" name="add" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Home Address" value="{{ hno }}" type="text">
                  </div>  
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="input-city" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="City" value="{{ city }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-country">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" name="country" id="input-country" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Country" value="{{ country }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-country">Postal code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pin" id="input-postal-code" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Postal code" value="{{ pin }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Update</button>
                </div>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </form>
```

But when i click on submit button the page redirects to itself and nothing happens.
Django Views

```
def update(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    id=request.POST['id']
    email=request.POST['email']
    name=request.POST['name']
    add=request.POST['add']+','+request.POST['city']+','+request.POST['country']+','+request.POST['pin']
    companydb.objects.get(id=id).update(email=email,name=name,address=add)
```

Django URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.login, name='login'),
path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
path('logout/',views.logout,name='logout'),
path('profile/',views.profile,name='profile'),
path('profile/',views.update,name='update'),
```

]

I cant find out what is wrong with my code everything works fine no errors are shown

Comment: Is that your complete code for the `update` view? you don't seem to be redirecting or rendering any template there? Also how do you expect to end up on the update view!! Your url patterns for `profile` and `update` are the same!

Comment: There are 2 views with same url in your urlconf - 'profile/'. Only first will be called.